# UIToolBar With Status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have a problem with a view where the Toolbar appears underneath the status bar.

**In Interface Builder my view looks like...**

[image: Interface Builder]

**The code that assembles the view controllers...**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.mainVC = [[ChartVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChartVC_iPad" bundle:nil];
    CGRect oldFrame = self.window.frame;
    self.mainVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height - 20);
    self.window.rootViewController = self.mainVC;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

**And how it appears in the simulator...** - (Notice the extra 20px space at the bottom)

[image: Simulator]

So my question is, how can I correctly position the Toolbar and get rid of the white space at the bottom?

*Edit: Added frame code...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a view controller as window's root will adjust its view's frame to window's frame, which is same as screen bounds and therefore includes status bar.

Replace `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]` with `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]]` which will return a rect with status bar cut off and your window will start below status bar, so you don't even need to do anything with your view's frame, it will get set properly by the window.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

    self.mainVC = [[ChartVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChartVC_iPad" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.mainVC;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: Genius... although its given me another problem now ;)

Comment: The Toolbar doesn't stay glued, but I shall debug first before I post another question! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow for the status bar. This happens automatically if the root view controller is a tab or navigation controller, but this isn't the case for you. To quote from Apple's [view programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html):

> For applications that show an opaque status bar, position your view
>   below the status bar and reduce its size accordingly. Subtracting the
>   status bar height from the height of your view prevents the top
>   portion of your view from being obscured.

In your case you'll want to adjust the frame of `mainVC` so that its y-origin is offset by the status bar height (20 pts).

Do bear in mind that in iOS 7 the status bar is not opaque by default, so you may need to add some extra code to handle iOS 6/7 differences.

Comment: Ok, but it goes on to read 'And if you are using view controllers, the view controller should handle the sizing of your views automatically' How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the toolbar like this:

[image]